# Runtime property in Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, properties, option-type

I am defining an object that needs properties computed at runtime to avoid redundancy. For example :

```js
export class Assessment {
    items: Question[];
    time?: number; // optional property
    scoreTotal?: number; // runtime computed property (sum of questions scores)
}

export class Question {
    score: number;
    statement: string;
    responses: string[];
    correctResponse: string;
}
```

`scoreTotal?` works but it can be misleading (one could think it's optional).

Is there another approach ?

**Edit :** I wish to avoid using a method since I am reading this property multiple times. I would like to set it once.

Answer (score 2):

Split `Assessment` into 2 types; with and without the `scoreTotal`. You can do it most elegantly with "tagged union" types.

```
interface AssessmentBase {
    items: Question[];
    time?: number; // optional property
}

interface AssessmentWithoutScoreTotal extends AssessmentBase {
    type: "AssessmentWithoutScoreTotal",
}

interface AssessmentWithScoreTotal extends AssessmentBase {
    type: "AssessmentWithScoreTotal",
    scoreTotal: number; // runtime computed property (sum of questions scores)
}

type Assessment = AssessmentWithoutScoreTotal
    & AssessmentWithScoreTotal;
```

Of course, `Assessment` will no longer be a class. But you can make either of `AssessmentWithoutScoreTotal` or `AssessmentWithScoreTotal` be a class, depending on your needs. Does it really have to be a class, though? I find that plain interfaces work much better in most situations.

Still, you'd have to be careful to not change the `items` property after computing the `totalScore`, so it might make sense to type that as well:

```
interface Question {
    readonly score: number;
    statement: string;
    responses: string[];
    correctResponse: string;
}

interface AssessmentBase {
    time?: number; // optional property
}

interface AssessmentWithoutScoreTotal extends AssessmentBase {
    type: "AssessmentWithoutScoreTotal",
    items: Question[];
}

interface AssessmentWithScoreTotal extends AssessmentBase {
    type: "AssessmentWithScoreTotal",
    scoreTotal: number; // runtime computed property (sum of questions scores)
    readonly items: readonly Question[]; // Shouldn't mutate the scores anymore, since total has been precomputed.
}

type Assessment = AssessmentWithoutScoreTotal
    & AssessmentWithScoreTotal;
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about union types. What is the point of adding `type: "AssessmentWithoutScoreTotal",` ?

Comment: Tagged unions (also "discriminated unions") lets you do type checking based on the `type` property, and the compiler will know what other properties are available. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways:

1. Assign it when the class is created. I also made it `readonly` but that is not necessary.

```js
export class Assessment {
  items: Question[];
  time?: number;

  // You can assign it like this when the class is created
  readonly scoreTotal: number = this.computeTotalScoreSomehow();

  // You can also use the items and pass them to some external function
  readonly scoreTotal: number = computeTotalScoreSomehow(this.items);

  // Or do it in the constructor
  constructor(items: Question[]) {
    this.items = items;
    this.scoreTotal = /* Leave this up to you :) */
  }
}
```

2. Make it truly computed using a `get` accessor.

```js
export class Assessment {
  items: Question[];
  time?: number;

  get scoreTotal(): number {
    return calculateScoreSomehow() // Up to you :)
  }
}
```

Comment: The first solution is fine and short but I wish to keep logic and types definition separated. I'm using Angular and a service to initialize my object from json. The second approach re-eveluate the score each time, so I think it is not optimal. But the first one